# render multiple variable in Json from rails to react

Tags: ruby-on-rails, reactjs

I want to display a list of meals from my rails backend to my react frontend. In addition, I'd like to add a specific date.

Here is what I have so far:

meals_controller.rb

```
  def index
    @meals = Meal.where(week_day: Date.today.cwday).order('random()')
    @date = DateTime.now

    render json: @meals.to_json(include: :restaurant)
  end
```

MealsPage.js:

```
componentDidMount() {
    axios.get('/meals.json')
    .then(response => {
        this.setState({
            meals: response.data
        });
    })
    .catch(error => console.log(error))
}
```

I'd like to add `@date`in the render method so that I could do something like:

```
this.setState({
     meals: response.data.meals,
     date: response.data.date
            });
```

But everything I have tried so far has failed. I've tried things like:

```
render json: [@meals.to_json(include: :restaurant), @date]
```

or

```
render json: {meals: @meals.to_json(include: :restaurant), date: @date}
```

But both of these solutions send my `@meals` as one big string like `"[{}, {}, {}]"` instead of rendering it as an array of objects.

Any idea on I can make this work ?

Comment: how exactly it is not working? and did it work before you decided to add more nesting in there?

Comment: Hi @potashin, I does work when I only have my `meals` to render. The data are fetched from the backend correctly but it is on the react that the error is raised: `reponse.data.meals` does not seem to work.

Comment: @potashin I just realised that my meals are rendered as one big string instead of an array of hash. I update my post to make it clearer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should use [`as_json`](https://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveModel/Serializers/JSON.html) instead if `to_json` here:

```
render json: { meals: @meals.as_json(include: :restaurant), date: @date }
```

Comment: thank you very much for your help @potashin ! It did the trick perfectly.